# Which fork of apn_on_rails is better for rails3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm actually using apn_on_rails for sending Apple Push Notification from a rails3 web-app.

The fork I'm using is https://github.com/natescherer/apn_on_rails but I noticed there are some more recent forks.

Have someone tried some different fork? Any suggestion?

Comment: I've actually started using this other fork https://github.com/timsu/apn_on_rails. It works pretty good for me. I'd only like to have a persistent connection to the apple APN server.

Comment: Today I've tried 4 forks an each one of them has their own problem. I can't believe it's 2013 and we still don't have a good maintained branch for apn_on_rails...

Answer (score 0):

Natescherer's rails 3 branch worked well when I was using it, it's still out of date though and hasen't been touched in a while. I'd recommend checking out apn_sender https://github.com/kdonovan/apn_sender it's more fully featured and kept up to date, plus redis is neat!